# Auto scroll Item in every 5 seconds in ScrollView or FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have component that can be wrap in scrollview. I want to scroll the automatic in every 5 seconds like sideshow.

Here is my code:

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 20, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <ScrollView style={{ padding: 10 }} horizontal={true}>
        {Data.map((data, index) => {
            return (
                  <View key={index}>
                    <CustomerComp
                      imgLink={data.imgLink}
                      customerText={data.customerText}
                      customerName={data.customerName}
                    />
                  </View>
                )
        })}
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use flatlist with scrollToIndex(params); method
for example

```
const ref = useRef();
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
useEffect(()=> {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
ref?.current?.scrollToIndex({index, animated: true});
setIndex(index + 1);
}, 5000);
return () => clearInterval(interval);
},[]);

return(
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <FlatList ref={ref} data={Data} {...props} />
      </View>
);
```